# Android: How to Touchables two page on ViewPager?

Tags: android

When open app `setCurrent(1)`

[image]

Changed to page 0

[image]

At this time, i only click on page 0, but i want i click the buttons +,-,.. on page 1.

Who can help me? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please throw more light on the issue you're facing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain what you want. The information provided is not adequate. You may probably need to check out fragments!